# Join in two tables?

Tags: php, mysql

I have problem with join in two tables I search tutorial but I can't find anything to help me.

I have two tables in SQL | members | and | gallery |  structure of gallery is id - member_id - picname. How can I join gallery table to members and limit number of shown pictures? Because I have list of all members and I want to just one picture be shown per member. Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT m.*, g.picname
FROM members m
LEFT JOIN gallery g ON g.member_id=m.id
GROUP BY m.id
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use the sql JOIN,The JOIN keyword is used in an SQL statement to query data from two or more tables, based on a relationship between certain columns in these tables.

- JOIN: Return rows when there is at least one match in both tables
- LEFT JOIN: Return all rows from the left table, even if there are no matches in the right table
- RIGHT JOIN: Return all rows from the right table, even if there are no matches in the left table
- FULL JOIN: Return rows when there is a match in one of the tables

Answer (score 0):

It may be useful to have subquery on this,

```
SELECT  a.*, b.minPic
FROM    members a
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT member_ID, MIN(picname) minPic
            FROM gallery
            GROUP BY memberID
        )
            ON a.id = b.member_ID
```